# Is there a sprite sheet creator that satisfies these requirements?

Tags: graphics, tools, linux, spritesheet

I'm looking for a decent sprite sheet packer.

Features:

- Command line interface for Linux.
- Effective packing algorithm.
- Configurable padding between sprites in the sheet.
- Configurable fixed sprite sheet size (i.e. pack to many sheets).
- Duplicate sprites detection, preferably with some tolerance to allow for FP errors when packing rasterized vector images.
- Auto-crop by transparent pixels (i.e. sprite is cropped when packed and it is correctly reflected in the data).
- Support for web-graphics formats (jpg, png at least).
- Reasonable data output format (sprite sheet indes).

Paid software is okay as long as the price is reasonable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My [TexturePacker](http://www.texturepacker.com) currently supports Ubuntu. What Linux would you need?
The command line works too - and it has all the features you need.

Comment: Ubuntu it is. Will check out texturepacker, thanks for all who answered. Will accept some answer when we will decide on what to use.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked [TexturePacker](http://www.texturepacker.com/)? It has a considerable list of [features](http://www.texturepacker.com/features/) and at first sight seems to cover all or most of the features you listed. For instance, it seems to work under linux and has a command line tool that you can plug into your build process. Also seems to be capable of detecting and handling duplicates.

As for the price, it states on the front page that most features are available for free. If you need one of the features that aren't available, you can [request a free license](http://www.texturepacker.com/request-free-license/) if you're a blogger or a framework developer. Otherwise the full price at the moment seems to be [25$ for TexturePacker Pro](http://sites.fastspring.com/codeandweb/product/all).

Comment: i tried this, and the free version adds "watermark" on some sprites, so i wouldnt say its usable as is.

Comment: It only adds the watermarks if you use "pro" features. Before you publish you get a list if features which trigger the water marks. E.g. color reduction, dithering etc.

Answer (score 1):

John Ratcliff has a [code snippet](http://codesuppository.blogspot.com/2009/04/texture-packing-code-snippet-to-compute.html) to do this, and it's hosted on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/texture-atlas/). You'd still have to write the command-line code around it, though.

Answer (score 0):

[TexturePacker](http://www.texturepacker.com) does all of the things you're looking for. There's a Linux version but according to this (rather old) [post](http://www.texturepacker.com/texturepacker/linux-version-is-here-at-least-a-bit/), the command-line interface isn't working yet. I don't know if that has been fixed in the mean time or if it's still an issue.